# Calculate limit of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k^2 - 4n^2} $$

or prove it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Riemann sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k^2-4 n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k/n)^2-4}$$

> Thus the limit as $n \to \infty$ is
>
> $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2-4} = -\frac12 \int_0^{\pi/6} d\theta \, \sec{\theta} = -\frac14 \log{3}$$

Comment: I'm not saying I'm free of sin, but one can leave a little to the OP. Or use `>!` to place spoilers.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: sure, I agree and thanks for the tip.  Not to split hairs, but I did leave plenty to the OP; the above is merely an outline of a solution with several steps missing.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You can use Riemann Sums. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472579/evaluating-sum-of-limits).